# Serialize and deserialize in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++

What should be the appropriate way to serialize/deserialize data in `c#` or in `c++`.

If i serialize it in `c#` I need to deserialize it in `c++` and reverse. Please advise.

Comment: What do you want to serialize? Object won't match 1:1 per language. I suggest JSON if it is for data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)

The like is `protobuf` which is designed to be cross-platform to (Serialize and Deseialize)

You may see c++ version from `protobuf` and c# free one also

Other options to use XML, or JSON